# how can I login to docker hub via Vagrant docker provisioner

Tags: docker, vagrant, provisioning

I've read [this documentation](http://docs.vagrantup.com/v2/docker/configuration.html)

I have a question what is the correct way to login via `vagrant` to `docker` hub?

```
config.vm.provision "docker" do |d|
  d.login <- doesn't exist
  d.username <- doesn't exist
end
```

so, I think I need help. 
Does anybody know how should I do that?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

I could not find a way using the Vagrant docs so did the following:

```
Vagrant.configure(2) do |config|
  config.vm.box = "hashicorp/precise64"
  #provision with docker
  config.vm.provision "docker"

  # login to docker
  config.vm.provision "shell", inline: "docker login -e donald@trump.com -p mexican_wall -u donald_trump"

  # then run your docker config
  config.vm.provision "docker" do |d|
    d.run "ubuntu"
  end
end
```

Answer (score 0):

Are you using the proper vagrant version?

Try

```
Vagrant.configure("2") do |config|
  config.vm.provision "docker" do |d|
    d.email = ""
    d.username = ""
    d.password = ""
  end
end
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you want to use `d.email` rather than login in this case. Not super familiar with Vagrant's docker provisioner, but the four parameters provided for access to a repository are `email`, `username`, `password`, and `auth_server`.

Answer (score 0):

You could also login in the host and use the generated credentials in `~/.docker/config.json`. Something like that should work:

```
Vagrant.configure("2") do |config|
  config.vm.box = "generic/ubuntu2010"

  config.vm.provision "file", source: "~/.docker/config.json", destination: "/tmp/config.json"
  config.vm.provision "shell", inline: "mkdir -p /root/.docker && cp /tmp/config.json /root/.docker/config.json"
  config.vm.provision "docker"
  config.vm.provision "shell", inline: "docker login <your_server>"
  config.vm.provision "docker" do |d|
    d.pull_images "<your_server>/<your_image>"
  end
end
```

I copy the `config.json` into `/tmp` first because the `"file"` provisioner don't have permissions to write under `/root/` directory, but the `"shell"` provisioner does.